Custom orange learner in python script is failing
I am trying to implement a custom learner in Orange similar to the stack learner.

The input learners return yes, no and maybe. I want to implement an aggregate learner that takes the values of multiple input learners and applies the following rule

If any yes => yes
Else if any maybe => maybe
Otherwise => no

I have tried this with the following code. It seams to work with the debug statements I added to the bottom (taken from applying learners documentation). This enabled me to reproduce the errors I got in my in the Test and Score step. After I fixed those by returning the values from the input learners, I get an error in the Test and Score that I cannot reproduce or fix.
MedicaLearner failed with error: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars


This is the python code for my learner:
from Orange.classification import Learner, Model
from Orange.preprocess import Continuize, RemoveNaNColumns, SklImpute, Normalize
from Orange.data.filter import HasClass
from Orange.data import Table
from operator import countOf
from Orange.evaluation import CrossValidation
from Orange.evaluation.scoring import CA, AUC
import numpy as np


import datetime;
ct = datetime.datetime.now()
print("current time:-", ct)


class MedicalLearner(Learner):
    def __init__(self, preprocessors=[HasClass(), Continuize(), RemoveNaNColumns(), SklImpute()]):
        super().__init__(preprocessors=preprocessors)
        self.name = 'MedicalLearner'
        
    def fit_storage(self, data):
        classifiers = [l(data) for l in in_learners]
        return MedicalModel(data, classifiers)


class MedicalModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, data, classifiers):
        super().__init__(data.domain)
        self.domain = data.domain
        self.classifiers = classifiers

    def callClassifier(self, X, classifier):
        Y = np.zeros((len(X), len(self.domain.class_vars)))
        Y[:] = np.nan
        table = Table(self.domain, X, Y)
        return classifier(table)

    def predict(self, X):
        cs = [self.callClassifier(X, c) for c in self.classifiers]
        values = [self.domain.class_var.values[int(c)] for c in cs]
        value_map = {self.domain.class_var.values[int(c)] : c for c in cs}
        
        yes, no, maybe = countOf(values, "yes"), countOf(values, "no"), countOf(values, "maybe")
        if yes > 0: 
            return value_map["yes"]
        elif maybe > 0: 
            return value_map["maybe"]
        elif no > 0: 
            return value_map["no"]
        else: 
            return value_map["maybe"]


out_learner = MedicalLearner()

# Test the learner by applying it in code
classifiers = [l(in_data) for l in in_learners]
cs = [c(in_data[0]) for c in classifiers]
values = [in_data.domain.class_var.values[int(c)] for c in cs]

print([type(c) for c in cs])
print(values)

print(type(in_data[0]))
print(type(in_data[0].x))

print(out_learner(in_data)(in_data[0]))

The debug script output is:
Running script:
current time:- 2024-04-22 23:09:56.891111
[<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.int64'>]
['no', 'no']
<class 'Orange.data.table.RowInstance'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1
>>> 

Any help would be greatly appreciated, either to fix the issue, reproduce the issue in my test or find the stacktrace for the error in the Test and Score step.
